# Apply function on a rolling slice of a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I'd like to calculate the determinant of 2x2 matrices which are taken by rolling a window of size 2 on a Nx2 matrix. I'm just using the determinant as an example function. In general, I'd like to apply a function to a dataframe which is taken by windowing a larger dataframe.

For example, this is a single 2x2 matrix and I calculate the determinant like so:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = pd.DataFrame({
   "X": [1,2],
   "Y": [3,4]
   })
np.linalg.det(d)
```

Now, I can form 4 2x2 matrices by sliding a window of size 2 along axis=0 of the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "A": [1,2,3,4,5],
    "B": [6,7,8,9,10],
  })
```

which looks like:

```
    A   B
0   1   6
1   2   7
2   3   8
3   4   9
4   5   10
```

so I would get [-5., -5., -5., -5.]

As far as I can see, pandas.DataFrame.rolling and rolling.apply can only be applied on a 1D vector, not a dataframe? How would you do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
#You can replace np.linalg.det with other functions as you like.
#use apply to get 'A' and 'B' from current row and next row and feed them into the function.
df.apply(lambda x: np.linalg.det(df.loc[x.name:x.name+1, 'A':'B']) if x.name <(len(df)-1) else None,axis=1)

Out[157]: 
0   -5.0
1   -5.0
2   -5.0
3   -5.0
4    NaN
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 7):

Extract a numpy array from your dataframe:

```
>>> array = df.values
>>> array
array([[ 1,  6],
       [ 2,  7],
       [ 3,  8],
       [ 4,  9],
       [ 5, 10]])
```

Use numpy's `as_strided` function to create your sliding window view:

```
>>> from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

>>> rows, cols = array.shape
>>> row_stride, col_stride = array.strides
>>> windowed_array = as_strided(
...     array,
...     shape=(rows - 2 + 1, 2, cols),
...     strides=(row_stride, row_stride, col_stride))
>>> windowed_array
array([[[ 1,  6],
        [ 2,  7]],

       [[ 2,  7],
        [ 3,  8]],

       [[ 3,  8],
        [ 4,  9]],

       [[ 4,  9],
        [ 5, 10]]])
```

And now apply your function to the resulting array:

```
>>> np.linalg.det(windowed_array)
array([-5., -5., -5., -5.])
```

Answer (score 2):

Use list comprehension to do your own rolling:

```
s = pd.Series([np.linalg.det(df.iloc[i:i+2]) for i in range(df.shape[0]-1)])
```

Output:

```
0   -5.0
1   -5.0
2   -5.0
3   -5.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

This question has been asked before. However in your case a straightforward workaround would be:

```
df['A'] * df['B'].shift(-1) - df['A'].shift(-1) * df['B']
```

Output:

```
0   -5.0
1   -5.0
2   -5.0
3   -5.0
4    NaN
```

Comment: This method is definitely faster than using apply, but OP has specified that he's looking for a method to make `rolling().apply()` work with more than one column of data (and determinant was just an example function).